# Option added by jQuery is in HTML but not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have kind of a weird issue.

I'm trying to dynamicaly build options for a select with jQuery. First I tried many ways of doing it .append() .html() and many more but nothing was working.

I then look at it a bit closer and saw that the option was present in the HTML but not showing.

I don't understand why, I searched for similar issues but didn't found any so I created this post.

Here are the infos:

My select is ->

```
<select id="select_critere" name="select_critere">
    <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
```

My JS is ->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#select_critere").append("<option value='1'>HeLLo</option>");
});
```

My Result HTML is ->

[image]

Only one option showing ->

[image]

Any idea of what could it be ? For info I'm using Smarty but there is no interaction with it in this case.

Comment: put your code rather then screenshot.

Comment: You might have some cache issues or something, because you can see it work in this example: https://codepen.io/zmuci/pen/pLzGKv

Comment: Check the `css` for your `select` I can see jqTransform**Hidden** in the class so maybe it's hiding something?

Comment: I switched screenshots for code sorry, ok thanks I go investigate :)

Comment: @NewToJS Indeed it is, I removed the class and can now see my option I gonna try find out how to deal with this

Comment: Or maybe add something like `$( "#select_critere" ).removeClass( "jqTransformHidden" );` after your append just for the sake of debugging rather than searching the `css`

Comment: Didn't thought about removing the class from jQuery, thanks for the insight

Comment: @Folder check the `css` in the browser inspection tools, maybe you can over write a specific style property.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your js into

```
 $("#select_critere").append(new Option("Hello", "1"));
```